# Load winmd library from within UWP app using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, uwp, windows-runtime, winmd

I want to load a windows runtime component (winmd file) written in c#, from our UWP app which is written in C++, using reflection.

But `Assembly.load()` fails with exception that assembly is not found. Is it possible to load winmd based assemblies via reflection in UWP (Win 10 store) apps?

Comment: Hi @user10436320 and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you post some code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: You could add reference to this c# windows runtime component directly in your c++ UWP project. Why did you want to use reflection?